# Relative path links are not working in iphone

Tags: iphone, reactjs, svg, hyperlink, relative-path

I created an SVG menu for a single page website. When I use the menu from my computer everything works fine, but when I try to access from my phone, the links are not working. I noticed that the issue only happens if I use relative paths (I am only linking to the Id of the element) and with Iphones, I don’t have any issues with Android devices. My problem is that if I use absolute paths, I lose the scroll-behavior animation (smooth).

I don't know if this is issue with my SVG or that I simply can't use relative path in iphones.

This is the link for my project: http://portfolio-2019-cg.herokuapp.com

I am using React to create this website.

```
    <div>
    <svg className="circle" width="611px" onClick={this.showMenu} height="883px" viewBox="0 0 611 883" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" strokeWidth="1" fill="none" fillRule="evenodd">
            <path id='menu' className={this.state.activeclass} d="M611,473 L611,708 C611,804.649831 532.649831,883 436,883 L269,883 L60,883 C26.862915,883 1.11635499e-14,856.137085 7.10542736e-15,823 L1.08387875e-15,473 L-1.42108547e-14,60 C-1.82689772e-14,26.862915 26.862915,6.08718376e-15 60,0 L551,0 C584.137085,-6.08718376e-15 611,26.862915 611,60 L611,473 Z" id="Combined-Shape" fill="#FF531B"></path>
            <circle id="Oval" fill="#FF531B" cx="436" cy="708" r="175"></circle>
            <path className={this.state.plusclass} onClick={this.showMenu} d="M486,658.5 L561.5,658.5 L561.5,758.5 L486,758.5 L486,834 L386,834 L386,758.5 L310.5,758.5 L310.5,658.5 L386,658.5 L386,583 L486,583 L486,658.5 Z" id="Combined-Shape" fill="#080815"></path>
            <g className={this.state.menuclass}>
            <text id="HOME" fontSize="94" fontWeight="normal" fill="#080815">
            <a xlinkHref="#home">
            <tspan x="205.181641" y="140">Home</tspan>
            </a>
            </text>
            <text id="ABOUT" fontSize="94" fontWeight="normal" fill="#080815">
            <a xlinkHref="#about">
            <tspan x="176.977051" y="270">About</tspan>
            </a>
            </text>
            <text id="PORTFOLIO" fontSize="94" fontWeight="normal" fill="#080815">
            <a xlinkHref="#portfolio">
            <tspan x="64.1586914" y="400">Portfolio</tspan>
            </a>
            </text>
            <text id="CONTACT" fontSize="94" fontWeight="normal" fill="#080815">
            <a xlinkHref="#contact">
            <tspan x="120.567871" y="530">Contact</tspan>
            </a>
            </text>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>  
</div>
```

Comment: Which browser on which devices? It works fine for me in Chrome on Android.

Comment: I tested it with an Iphone X using Safari and Chrome